# In Form view the the value of the field is coming in the next line while edit in Odoo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, odoo

I'm having the form view which consists of different fields. when im trying to edit the value of the field is going to the next line.

```xml
<div class="row">
  <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-2 font-weight-bold" style = "padding-right: 5px;border-right: 1px solid grey"/>
  <field name="website" select="1" placeholder="should be integer" id="field_id" style = "padding-left:5px"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label string="Apply on first" for="field_id" class="col-2 font-weight-bold" style = "padding-right: 5px;border-right: 1px solid grey"/>
  <field name="start_date" id="field_id"  style = "padding-left:5px"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label string="End Date" for="field_id" class="col-2 font-weight-bold" style = "padding-right: 5px;border-right: 1px solid grey"/>
  <field name="end_date" id="field_id" style = "padding-left:5px"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label string="Start Date" for="field_id" class="col-2 font-weight-bold" style = "padding-right: 5px;border-right: 1px solid grey"/>
  <field name="is_active" id="field_id"  style = "padding-left:5px"/>
</div>
```

For this I see the output as below

[image: Output IMAGE]

Issue which I'm facing is while i click on Edit in form, by dividing the vertical Line the value of the field in the next line instead of the same row as below.

[image: Issue Image]

Comment: Code provide is HTML? If so the `<field>` element doesn't exist, and the `<label>` element need to have a closing friend like : `<label>text</label>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved when I added `class="oe_inline"` in Field Tag.